# Loop through the .sql file and executing each statement in it using perl script

Tags: sql, perl, parsing, oracle11g

I have a `.sql` file which contains multiple SQL statements. I need to loop over each statement and execute them from a Perl script. The problem is that the SQL statements are multiline statements and they include comments.

Up until now, we used the `sqlplus` command manually. But now we need to automate it to execute every statement and capture the success or failure of each statement. If a statement fails, I need to stop executing SQL statements from the file. As far I know, this isn't possible with `sqlplus`; it goes on executing the remaining statements after one of the statement fails.

The `.sql` file looks as below....

```
--Add new columns to TABLE_NAME table

ALTER TABLE "DATA"."TABLE_NAME" ADD(NAME varchar2(30));

--Create new table FILE_4G_TABLE

CREATE TABLE "DATA"."FILE_4G_TABLE"
(

 abc VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),

 def NUMBER(38),

 ghi NUMBER,

 JKL VARCHAR(32)

CONSTRAINT "FILE_4G_TABLE" PRIMARY KEY ("abc")) TABLESPACE "DATA";
```

Someone, please guide me.

Comment: So you want to parse SQL. Try [SQL::Statement](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SQL::Statement).

Comment: What flavour of SQL is being used? (For which database server?)

Comment: oracle data base.I am using DBI for it.

Comment: How you communicate with the database is of no importance. You're not trying to do that; you're trying to parse SQL statements.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the sql file and push all statements in an array, then loop over the array and use [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) to prepare and execute the statements. [SQL::Statement](https://metacpan.org/pod/SQL::Statement) might be helpful as [suggested by ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41356426/loop-through-the-sql-file-and-executing-each-statement-in-it-using-perl-script/41356515#comment69914530_41356426).

Answer (score 0):

Presupposing your SQL file is not huge, something like this might work.  I'm making a huge leap here that splitting by ';' is enough to separate statements.  If you had a ';' in a comment or within a literal, that would pretty much mess things up.

```
use strict;

use DBI;
use DBD::Oracle;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:MyOracleService', 'user', 'password');

$/ = undef;
open my $IN, '<', 'test.sql' or die;
my $sql = <$IN>;
close $IN;

foreach my $mini_sql (split /;/, $sql) {
  $dbh->do($mini_sql);
}

$dbh->disconnect;
```

Also, this example was Oracle...  if your DBMS is something else...  well, you know.